# How can I change the difficulty during the game in The Witcher?

Tags: pc, mods, the-witcher

In the Witcher you choose a difficulty level at the start and can't change it thereafter.

I've played through a fair way and would like to change difficulty without restarting and having to play through from the start again.

As this isn't in the core game, I was wondering if there are any mods or other methods of changing the difficulty level?  I've had a search, but can only find mods to up the difficulty to 'very difficult' which isn't what I'm looking for (I'm helping my wife to play through on easy and thinking of switching up to medium)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to change the difficulty later in the game but you can use mods for that like: http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_settings_mod

Comment: The link is deelted: `Housekeeping: we shouldn't be hosting mini-mods, especially as we can't verify if they're updated` What a bunch of bastards.