# Change difficulty to hard in The Witcher

Tags: the-witcher

I want to change the difficulty in The Witcher 1 to hard in an existing save.

I found this: http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_settings_mod

But it doesn't show what the settings would be for hard, only easy and normal.

Comment: related to - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/how-can-i-change-the-difficulty-during-the-game-in-the-witcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can use the instructions on the page:

> The difficulty settings are governed by the script in:
>
> `\DATA\SCRIPTS00.BIF\witcher_atr_abl.luc`
>
> Decompile this script using any utility that is listed in [the LUC format article](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/LUC_format) under [the file formats category](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Category:File_Formats).
> Open up the resulting file in any text editor.

In the text editor you should be able to copy the settings for Hard into the settings for Easy or Normal (maybe back up the file in case you want to revert).  Then just recompile it and stick it back in.

---

**Edit:** The save file format is laid out [here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/TheWitcherSave_format).  I'm not sure whether difficulty is stored as a "resource" or not. If the resource names are plain text, it shouldn't be hard to figure out whether that is the case.

Comment: I meant I actually wanted to change the difficulty on my save, not change how the actual current difficulty plays out.

Comment: In that case, you should remove the second and third lines of your question; they're irrelevant.  The method I gave should still accomplish the same thing (increasing difficulty) but if you're after achievements and whatnot that can only be gotten on Hard, then it's not enough.

Comment: Going to mark as saved, but something is wrong here (the manual maybe) and I'm going to open a new question.